# How do I execute commands installed by a snap package?

Tags: snap

I installed snap package microk8s, but I cannot execute the included command `microk8s.kubectl`. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Directory `/snap/bin` contains symbolic links to the installed snap applications. Add this directory to your path:

```
PATH=/snap/bin:$PATH
```

You should also add this to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.